# How Do I Change Alternative Text In An Excel Chart Sheet without Selecting It

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I would like to change the alternative text in a chart sheet in excel.

When I record a macro this is the code that is recorded.

```
Sheets("Chart1").select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").AlternativeText = "asdasd"
```

I want to do this without executing the .select method.
This will allow me to edit chart sheets which are hidden without unhiding them.

This is how I do the same for charts in worksheets

```
Set sht_Sheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i_SheetCount)
For Each shp_Shape In sht_Sheet.Shapes
s_TitleText = shp_Shape.AlternativeText
next
```

Note I am editing Chart Sheets here, not charts in worksheets

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both the worksheet and chart are named Chart1?  If so, this should do it:

```
Sheets("Chart1").Shapes("Chart1").AlternativeText = "asdasd"
```

Comment: Sure but I don't want to refer to the shapes by their name (eg. Chart 1) as this will change often and could be anything.

Comment: What would you like to refer to them by then?  They are generally in a collection.  You could use the index so long as you aren't adding or removing them, or account for such activities.

Comment: Sure - they are definitely in a collection. What collection are they in? That is the problem I am having, show me the loop which allows me to loop through all objects on a chart without having to refer to them directly. Something like:

For each MySheet In Workbook.sheets
 For each MyShape In MySheet
   MyText = MyShape.AlternativeText
 Next
Next

Except the code above obviously does not work.